# How can I display xlsx file in an iframe

Tags: excel, iframe

I need to display excel files(xls, xlsx) in an iframe. 
Is this possible? If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Can't really be done. Excel files do not display natively in a browser. iframes, in this context, are just like regular pages. You would have to solve the showing Excel files in a browser problem first.

The closest you could get is to have a program that reads the Excel file and then generates HTML based on its content.

Adobe ColdFusion can do this natively; other languages and platforms may require 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution would be to convert the file to pdf and display it in the iframe.